# Entity Form --> Submitted Data With Comments

Tags: entities, forms

I am trying to create a site that has the following workflow.

Users (A, B, C...) can submit an item/product for review (if the product isnt already in existence in our site) using an entityform.

Upon approval by the moderators, the submission data needs to become published content. This published content can now be reviewed and commented upon by all users of this site.

The problem resides in the fact that, at the end of the form submission and mod approval, that node needs to allow comments so that more people can review our website (using fivestar) in the comments field as well as a text field for leaving a text comment.

In Drupal 6 I could easily do this with Webform because it was a node. However, Entityforms are just that, an entity. You cannot attach comment fields to an entity. After viewing this page, it seems there are a few other people who would have the same need I do, but there is no solution (maybe Drupal 8)?

I have subscribed to [Convert comment settings into a field to make them work with CMI and non-node entities](https://www.drupal.org/node/731724) in hopes of seeing the direction Drupal will take with all the new entity methods incorporated into Drupal 7.

At this point, I can only think of one solution to get the submitted form content into a place on my site where it can get further reviews/ratings -- manually move over the data submitted in the form and put it into a content type/node so that I can get the comment functionality. It would be a bit of a PITA but Id rather do that than try and work with the reply module (reply module is not recommended on production sites).

Comment: I think the idea for this is to create Rules that convert the entityform data on moderation (or even on submission) to the appropriate node. It's a bit of a pain to set up, but it means you have clean nodes.